# Time and Work question - Case when people leave in between

Tags: algebra-precalculus, word-problem, ratio

Mr. X can do a job in 10 days, Mr. Y in 15 days and Mr. Z in 20 days.  They work together for 2 days.  Then Mr. X leaves the job.  Mr. Y leaves the job a day earlier to the completion of the work.  The job was completed in how many days ?

---

My attempt:-

Let total work be 60 units

Efficiency of X = 6 units / day

Efficiency of Y = 4 units / day

Efficiency of Z = 3 units / day

Work completed in first 2 days = (6+4+3) * 2 = 26 units

Work Remaining = 34 units

Y and Z can complete this remaining work at a combined efficiency of 7 units/ day in 34/7 days or on the partial 5th day of them working together, to be precise 4+(6/7) days , since Y leaves a day prior, therefore Y and Z together worked for 4 days and completed 4*7=28 units

Finally, the remaining work of 34-28 =6 units would be completed by Z alone in 2 days
Therefore total days required to complete the job = 2+4+2=8 days

---

However my answer is not matching with that of author.  Official answer given is 52/7 days

Comment: The official answer seems to assume that Mr. Y left exactly one day before the completion, during the partial day. But in your attempt, Z would work alone for $2$ days.

Comment: In your attempt, Z would work alone for $2$ days to complete $6$ units of work. If instead, Y and Z together complete the first $3$ units of that work, they would take $3/7$ days. Then the total time would decrease from $8$ days to $7 + 3/7 = 52/7$ days, the official answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Your use of efficiency for an assumed units of work (usually the L C M) is a very good strategy to avoid reciprocals.
- The other simplifying technique you can use is **to compute from both ends**, viz
- In first two days, $13*2 = 26$ units of work is completed, $34$ units remain.
- Looking from the end, on the last day, $Z$  completes $3$ units of work, $31$ units of work left for middle period
- Time needed for the  balance work by Y and Z can be now easily determined as $\dfrac{31}7 +3$ and the three  to give the book answer of $\boxed{\dfrac{52}7}$
- Note for future reference that whenever in such problems, it is said that someone(s) left $x$ days before completion of work, it **always** means **exactly** $x$ days before completion of work.

Answer (score 4):

The reason your method didn't work is that you assumed that worker Y would leave the job after a whole number of days; in real life that would probably be a reasonable assumption, but in these kind of questions that restriction does not exist. (Also, note in your solution worker Y actually left **two** full days before the job was finished.

The general setup for these types of questions is

$$\sum_{i=1}^k r_i t_i = n$$

where $r_i$ and $t_i$ are the work rate and time, respectively, for worker $i$ and $n$ is the number of jobs completed.

In this specific case, the equation you have to solve would be

$$\left( \frac{1}{10} \right) (2) + \left( \frac{1}{15} \right) (t-1) + \left( \frac{1}{20} \right) (t) = 1$$

which will yield the given solution.